# Nhibernate mapping of Table without Entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a Table And Entity called Software

---

### Software

- Id
- Serial
- Name
- LinkedSoftware (This field is in the Entity)

Then I have a Table LinkedSoftware with no Entity

---

### LinkedSofware

- BaseSoftwareId (Relationship with Software.Id)
- LinkedSoftwareId (Relationship with Software.Id)

I am struggling to setup my hibernate mapping file, keep getting mapping errors.
I have tried the following with no luck:

```
<set name="linkedSoftware" access="field" cascade="all-delete-orphan" table="LinkedSoftware">
  <many-to-many class="Software" column="BaseSoftwareId" />
  <many-to-many class="Software" column="LinkedSoftwareId" />
</set>

<many-to-one name="LinkedSoftware" column="BaseSoftwareId"       cascade="save-update" class="Software" />
<many-to-one name="LinkedSoftware" column="LinkedSoftwareId" cascade="save- update" class="Software" />-->
```

Is there anyone that can please point me in the right direction.
I tried to google but couldnt really find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make table `LinkedSotware` an entity, too. Then try write your `set` more like this:

```
 <set name="LinkedSoftware" table="LinkedSoftware">
  <key>
    <column name="BaseSoftwareId" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="LinkedSoftware" />
</set>
```

But not sure if that is everything, because that will give you into set just the `LinkedSoftware` instances which have the instance of `Software` as `BaseSoftware`. Sorry for my English, hope you understand.

And then in `LinkedSoftware` mapping:

```
<many-to-one name="BaseSoftware" class="Software">
<column name="BaseSoftwareId" />
</many-to-one>

<many-to-one name="LinkedSoftware" class="Software">
<column name="LinkedSoftwareId" />
</many-to-one>
```

This [NHibernate: Two foreign keys in the same table against same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964974/nhibernate-two-foreign-keys-in-the-same-table-against-same-column) could help you. And I would avoid using many-to-many, I think this would be more flexible. For many-to-many explanation see [Nhibernate: How to represent Many-To-Many relationships with One-to-Many relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510748/nhibernate-how-to-represent-many-to-many-relationships-with-one-to-many-relatio) .